# How does KillSignal interact with TimeoutStopSec in systemd?

Tags: linux, systemd

Can someone let me know the following about systemd service shutdown sequence

1. If I have specified `KillSignal=SIGTERM` then how does this interact
   this `TimeoutStopSec` ? Does this mean that during shutdown of
   service, first `SIGTERM` will be sent and if the service is still
   running after `TimeoutStopSec` `SIGKILL` will be sent (if `SendSIGKILL` is
   set to `yes`)? I am asking about the case where nothing is specified in
   ExecStop.
2. Does `TimeoutStopSec` take into account `ExecStop` and all `ExecPostStop`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been answered in [systemd email thread](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2020-April/044445.html). Posting the answer below

> > Can someone let me know the following about systemd service shutdown
> >     sequence
> >
> > ```
> > 1.
> >
> > If I have specified KillSignal=SIGTERM then how does this interact this
> > TimeoutStopSec ? Does this mean that during shutdown of service, first
> > SIGTERM will be sent and if the service is still running after
> > TimeoutStopSec SIGKILL will be sent (if SendSIGKILL is set to yes? I am
> > asking about the case where nothing is specified in ExecStop.
> > ```
>
> Yes, that's correct
>
> > ```
> > 2.
> >
> > Does TimeoutStopSec take into account ExecStop and all ExecPostStop?
> > ```
>
> TimeoutStopSec is for every command. If ExecStopPost command fails (or
>   times out) subsequent commands are not executed, but if each command 
>   requires almost TimeoutStopSec time, total execution time will be
>   close  to ExecStopPost commands multiplied by TimeoutStopSec.

Answer (score 0):

From that [systemd man](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)

> This option serves two purposes. First, it configures the time to wait
> for each ExecStop= command. If any of them times out, subsequent
> ExecStop= commands are skipped and the service will be terminated by
> SIGTERM. If no ExecStop= commands are specified, the service gets the
> SIGTERM immediately. This default behavior can be changed by the
> TimeoutStopFailureMode= option. Second, it configures the time to wait
> for the service itself to stop. If it doesn't terminate in the
> specified time, it will be forcibly terminated by SIGKILL (see
> KillMode= in systemd.kill(5)). Takes a unit-less value in seconds, or
> a time span value such as "5min 20s". Pass "infinity" to disable the
> timeout logic. Defaults to DefaultTimeoutStopSec= from the manager
> configuration file (see systemd-system.conf(5)).
>
> If a service of Type=notify sends "EXTEND_TIMEOUT_USEC=…", this may
> cause the stop time to be extended beyond TimeoutStopSec=. The first
> receipt of this message must occur before TimeoutStopSec= is exceeded,
> and once the stop time has extended beyond TimeoutStopSec=, the
> service manager will allow the service to continue to stop, provided
> the service repeats "EXTEND_TIMEOUT_USEC=…" within the interval
> specified, or terminates itself (see sd_notify(3)).